# SQL Get aggregate as 0 for non existing row using inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server to query these three tables that look like (there are some extra columns but not that relevant):

- Customers -> Id, Name
- Addresses -> Id, Street, StreetNo, CustomerId
- Sales -> AddressId, Week, Total

And I would like to get the total sales per week and customer (showing at the same time the address details). I have come up with this query

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Street, b.StreetNo, c.Week, SUM (c.Total) as Total
FROM Customers a
    INNER JOIN Addresses b ON a.Id = b.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN Sales c ON b.Id = c.AddressId
GROUP BY a.Name, c.Week, b.Street, b.StreetNo
```

and even if my SQL skill are close to none it looks like it's doing its job. But now I would like to be able to show 0 whenever the one customer don't have sales for a particular week (weeks are just integers). And I wonder if somehow I should get distinct values of the weeks in the Sales table, and then loop through them (not sure how)

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows for all customers and weeks.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the data that is available:

```
SELECT c.Name, a.Street, a.StreetNo, w.Week,
       COALESCE(SUM(s.Total), 0) as Total
FROM Customers c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT s.Week FROM sales s) w LEFT JOIN
     Addresses a
     ON c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON s.week = w.week AND s.AddressId = a.AddressId
GROUP BY c.Name, a.Street, a.StreetNo, w.Week;
```

Using table aliases is good, but the aliases should be abbreviations for the table names.  So, `a` for `Addresses` not `Customers`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Name,
       Street,
       StreetNo,
       Week,
       SUM( CASE
                WHEN Total IS NULL THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    Total
            END ) AS Total
FROM Customers a
JOIN Addresses b ON a.Id = b.CustomerId
RIGHT JOIN Sales c ON b.Id = c.AddressId
GROUP BY a.Name,
         c.Week,
         b.Street,
         b.StreetNo;
```

I have modified your statement in three places.  The first is I changed your join to `Sales` to a `RIGHT JOIN`.  This will join as it would with an `INNER JOIN`, but it will also keep the records from the table on the *right* side of the `JOIN` that do not have a matching record or group of records on the left, placing `NULL` values in the resulting dataset's fields that would have come from the left of the `JOIN`.  A `LEFT JOIN` works in the same way, but with any extra records in the table on the *left* being retained.

I have removed the word `INNER` from your surviving `INNER JOIN`.  Where `JOIN` is not preceded by a join type, an `INNER JOIN` is performed.  Both `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are considered correct, but the prevailing protocol seems to be to leave the `INNER` out, where the RDBMS allows it to be left out (which SQL-Server does).  Which you go with is still entirely up to you - I have left it out here for illustrative purposes.

The third change is that I have added a `CASE` statement that tests to see if the `Total` field contains a `NULL` value, which it will if there were no sales for that Customer for that Week.  If it does then `SUM()` would return a `NULL`, so the `CASE` statement returns a `0` instead.  If `Total` does not contain a `NULL` value, then the `SUM()` of all values of `Total` for that grouping is performed.

Please note that I am assuming that `Total` will not have any `NULL` values other than from the `RIGHT JOIN`.  Please advise me if this assumption is incorrect.

Please also note that I have assumed that either there will be no missing `Week`s for a `Customer` in the `Sales` table or that you are not interested in listing them if there are.  Again, please advise me if this assumption is incorrect.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I acknowledge what you are trying here, unfortunately the Count in line 6 is raising an exception as it's not in an aggregate function nor in the group by clause

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a week numbers, rather than using `DISTINCT`. This is better in terms of performance and reliability. Then use a `LEFT JOIN` on the Sales table instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT   a.Name
        ,b.Street
        ,b.StreetNo
        ,weeks.[Week]
        ,COALESCE(SUM(c.Total),0) as Total
FROM Customers a
    INNER JOIN Addresses b ON a.Id = b.CustomerId
    CROSS JOIN (
        -- Generate a sequence of 52 integers (13 x 4)
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.x) AS [Week]
        FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a(x)
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT x FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1)) b(x)) b
    ) weeks
    LEFT JOIN Sales c ON b.Id = c.AddressId AND c.[Week] = weeek.[Week]
GROUP BY a.Name
        ,b.Street
        ,b.StreetNo
        ,weeks.[Week]
```

Comment: You definitely have a point, in my case though the distinct makes more sense as I don't have all the weeks but a subset of them and with DISTINCT will fit better.